# Почему ошибка при отправки email?

Tags: java, spring

Я хочу отправить сообщение в Spring boot, Но при отправке сообщения
вводит ошибку:

> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 Error: authentication failed

Но я в secure gmail поставил галочку для других приложений.

В чем может быть проблема?

код:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SendMail {

private final JavaMailSender sender;

@RequestMapping("/test")
public String sendMail(){
    SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();

    mailMessage.setFrom("massage");
    mailMessage.setTo("omurturdubekov@gmail.com");
    mailMessage.setSubject("Здравствуйте!");
    mailMessage.setText("Отправил");
    sender.send(mailMessage);

    return "Message send!";
   }
  }
```

Comment: А случайно не двухфакторная у вас в гугле?

Comment: Добавьте код где вы задаете параметры для создания JavaMailSender

Comment: Спасибо, уже решил